# How To Display C# Objects in A Grid in xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im Looking for a way to display my C# Objects in a Grid. But even after serveral hours of searching I couldn't find a valid Way. How can I Achieve the following result?

[image: Screenshot of my wantet behaviour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first in your c# code create an observable collection of your object type;

```
        private ObservableCollection<YourModel> objList;
        public ObservableCollection<YourModel> ObjList
        {
            get { return objList; }
            set
            {
               objList = value;
            }
        }
```

add your data to the list:

```
ObjList = new ObservableCollection<YourModel>(){ new YourModel{ ...} , new YourModel{...} };
```

In xaml create a grid inside n collectionview :

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                   
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Label Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       />
                <Label 
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Att1}"
                      />
                     
                      <Label 
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="{Binding Att2}"
                        />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    ...
</CollectionView>
```

Alternatively Check DataGrid in syncfusion :
[check](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/getting-started)